# Upper bound on bilinear form $|u^*Av|$ with $(1-\delta)I\preceq A \preceq (1+\delta)I$

Tags: inner-products, random-matrices

I am interested in finding a better upper bound for $|u^*Av|$, with $A$ a random Hermitian matrix that satisfies $(1-\delta)I\preceq A \preceq (1+\delta)I$ with high probability- at least $1-C\mathrm{e}^{-c(\delta)}$, with $C$, $c$ absolute constants independent of $A$ or its size.

It's obvious that
\begin{align}
|u^*Av|\leq\|A\|\|u\|\|v\|
\end{align}
but I believe that there are cases where the bound can be improved, in particular for the off-diagonal terms, i.e. $|e_i^\mathsf{T}Ae_j|$ with $e_n$ the $n$-th canonical vector and $i\neq j$.

I am aware of the Hanson-Wright inequality for the tail of these inner products (see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134776/bilinear-form-tail-bound/134865#134865)), but wasn't sure how to use this to bound the inner product in reference to $\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(1-\delta)I \preceq A \preceq (1+\delta)I$ w.h.p., we have $-\delta I \preceq A-I \preceq \delta I$ w.h.p., i.e. $\|A-I\| \le \delta$ w.h.p.

Hence, we can trivially derive the bound
\begin{align*}
|u^*Av| &= \left|u^*v + u^*(A-I)v\right| 
\\
&\le |u^*v| + |u^*(A-I)v| 
\\
&\le |u^*v|+\|A-I\|\|u\|\|v\| 
\\
&\le |u^*v|+\delta\|u\|\|v\|
\end{align*} with high probability. If $u$ and $v$ are nearly parallel (or anti-parallel), this will be similar to the bound you obtained. But if $u$ and $v$ are nearly orthogonal and $\delta$ is small, this bound will be much smaller than $(1+\delta)\|u\|\|v\|$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was aiming for and didn't even realize this.